# Check database(phpmyadmin) for a user and allow that user access to the page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

**How do I check the database when someone logs in with their log in details and if the user is in that database then it will allow him/her access to the next page if not it will echo an error?

```
            <form action="profile_student.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p> <input type="text" name="user_login" placeholder="Email"  required/></p>
                <p><input type="password" name="user_pass" placeholder="Password" required/> </p>
                <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Log In"/> 
            </form>
        </div>
```

***

```
**<?php
//log in variables
$login_user = @strip_tags($_POST['user_login']);
$login_password = @strip_tags($_POST['user_pass']);
$login_submit = ($_POST['login_submit']);



if ($login_submit){
    $login_query = mysqli_query ($connect,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE e-mail = '$login_user' AND password = '$login_password'");
    // mae the query, now we check if the user exists
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows ($login_query);
    if ($check_user == 1) {
        // if there is a valid user in the db, if the results returned are one row, then log the user in, otherwise error


        // we need to create to session variables for  user so the user can log in, save details etc.
        $_SESSION["user_login"]=$login_submit;
        header("Location: profile_student.php");
        echo "logged in";
    }
?>**
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I have asked the question at the top of the code piece. Could you reply ASAP thanks.

Comment: any error in the code?@Aman.V

Comment: no error in the code just need the code to check the database when someone logs in with username and password and cross reference it to see if that user is there if not it will not allow access for that user.

Comment: @u_mulder have you got any suggestions?

Comment: @SanzeebAryal have you got any suggestions for me?

Comment: @Aman.V ok. what is the purpose of code you posted?